# How to store uploaded files using multer , Nodejs , JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, multer

I have multi part form data with one file input and several other text inputs , i have a dir named as ' public ' in which i have a dir named ' uploads ' i want to store all my multer uploads there , but can't figure out why they aren't uploading there , Below is my code (at last i will mention a ss of my file hirarchy)
**app.js** file

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const multer = require('multer');
let publicPath = path.join(__dirname , "../public");
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.use(express.static(publicPath));

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, '/uploads');
   },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null , file.originalname);
  }
});
var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/login');
    
})
app.get('/login',(req,res)=>{
  res.render('login-register/login');
})
app.get('/register',(req,res)=>{
  res.render('login-register/register');
})
// POST 
app.post('/login',(req,res)=>{

})
app.post('/register',upload.single('imageInput'),(req,res)=>{
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log("file size:"+req.file.size);
  console.log(req.file.path);
})
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

I can see everything like file size , file name but just i cant see where the files are being uploaded and i want them to go in ' ***uploads*** ' directory
Below is code for **reg.ejs** file

```
 <form class="row g-3 needs-validation login-form" method="POST" action="/register" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="profileImage">
          <img id="profileImage" src="/images/placeholder.jpg" alt="">
          <input type="file" name="imageInput" id="FileUpload1" style="display: none" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <label for="validationCustom01" class="form-label">Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" name="email" required>
          <div class="valid-feedback">
            Looks good!
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <label for="validationCustom02" class="form-label">Password</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom02" name="password" placeholder="atleast 6" required>
          <div class="valid-feedback">
            Looks good!
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <label for="validationCustomUsername" class="form-label">Username</label>
          <div class="input-group has-validation">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend">@</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustomUsername" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend" name="username" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Please choose a username.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="validationCustom03" class="form-label">CollegeName</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom03" name="collegeName" required>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Please provide a valid city.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <label for="validationCustom04" class="form-label">Branch</label>
          <select class="form-select" name="branch" id="validationCustom04" required>
            <option selected disabled value="">Choose...</option>
            <option>Mech/AutoMobile</option>
            <option>Electrical/Entc</option>
            <option>COMP/IT</option>
            <option>Civil</option>
            <option>Aerospace/Aeronautical</option>
            <option>Biotech</option>
            <option>Other</option>
          </select>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Please select a valid state.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <label for="validationCustom05" class="form-label">Sem</label>
          <input type="text" name="sem" class="form-control" id="validationCustom05" >
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Provide a sem (optional)
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="invalidCheck" required>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck">
              Agree to terms and conditions
            </label>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              You must agree before submitting.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

ss for my file hirarchy , as you can see the folder for named '**uploads** ' is empty , uploads is located inside the ' **public** ' folder
[image: HIRARCHY]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try relative path in your multer storage.
Since your app.js is under src

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, path.join(__dirname, '../public/uploads')););
   },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null , file.originalname);
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes this works thank you , But what was the problem with my way though , i set the publicPath in express.static() , so whenever i use ` / ` it should always refer to public directory !! so when i say ` /uploads ` it should know that by ` / ` i mean public directory as i had set in static() method

Comment: please answer my question mentioned in the above comment too , that will really clear my confusion too , thank you @Mohamed Oraby

Comment: Well, I had similar issue before that's why I knew what might be the problem, but I haven't really paid much thought to it since I rarely use multer. Try reading the documentation from multer it might have something to help